# Nvidia Optimus - how to run just an integrated gpu

Tags: nvidia-optimus, ubuntu-mate

I own 10 years old Samsung QX510 laptop with Nvidia Optimus technology and since Ubuntu 15.04 I'm facing huge problems with graphics.

Most of the time I was using just an integrated gpu and computer was working just fine with nomodeset in boot command.

Yesterday I've tried Ubuntu Mate 20.04. becasue they promised to solve optimus problems.
Now I can't even log in to Ubuntu becasue graphic crashes and screen freezes at login. With nomodeset some issue with sound card appears.
I need my laptop for work and I don't have enough free time now to repair it.

**Is there any way to install Ubuntu or some distribution to run just with integrated Intel gpu?**
Any sources of knowledge will also be very helpfull!
Thanks in advance for quick tips

Comment: Easy, don't install or allow to be installed any nvidia driver. Also do not use nomodeset kernel option.

Comment: Hmm... How to do it during system installation? Just by not clicking "install third-part components"? Then what happens with drivers for audio, network etc. Just that comes to my mind now...

Comment: You don't need any of the 3rd party stuff during install. I've never had to install anything for audio, network, ect..

Comment: If you cannot boot up without nvidia drivers then check in your bios/system setup to see if there is a discrete only option for graphics that has been enabled (rare option, most laptops don't have it though many have an option for integrated only..

Comment: Additionally  - normally on optimus if nvidia driver is installed you could go nvidia settings > Prime profiles and pick Intel.  (- your card, if 420m, should be using the 390.xx driver

Comment: Thanks doug! I've reinstalled Mate without third-part drivers and now I can log in. That's right, in previous installation I could switch cards in nvidia settings but there weren't as many settings available as it should be in program and sometimes I had to restart computer few times to switch it on successfully.

Comment: Now in some free time I have  to find a way to disable proprietary driver without loging into system (in case it will lock again) and try 390 and 340.108 drivers which are available in additional drivers

Comment: nvidia recommends the 390 for the 420m gpu. You can always boot up > go to a tty > log in > `sudo prime-select intel` & reboot.